# I can't import pandas on jupyter notebook. Restarts the kernel everytime

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to import pandas on jupyter notebook, however I continuously receive this message and the kernel continuously restarts:

-> Input: import pandas as pd

-> Output:
INTEL MKL ERROR: dlopen(/Users/nathanantonicelli/opt/anaconda3/lib/libmkl_core.dylib, 9): image not found.
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_core.dylib.
[I 17:58:32.760 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
kernel 0c5cfda8-b37e-4a9f-9105-361df952c9a3 restarted

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to do to fix this? I've already installed pandas and updated it to the latest version.

Comment: I think I had something similar once and updating my packages fixed it. For example, if you use (ana)conda, try running `conda update pandas` and `conda update jupyter` on the command line.